# PHP count cell data based on name

Tags: php, excel, vba

I've been doing a manual report for a while  on some data from a form and it's got quite excessive with the amount of data i'm getting now, it was 50 entries at first and now its over 500 so I need to find an easier way to manage it. I thought that a PHP program may make this easier.

Basically i have data like below, I need to sort by user and count how many leads each user has.

**Columns**

Username | Lead Source

Pete M, Lead 1

Fiona L, Lead 2

bare in mind that this csv file is quite large, I was wondering if anyone had a easier way to resolve this than me doing a manual excel formula.

many thanks,

Comment: Although not PHP I would suggest VBScript

Comment: I wouldn't suggest PHP as well, but instead of VBScript, I'd go for a database table approach. Would make managing the data sets easier in the long run.

Comment: Ah cheers guys, I've never really touched VBScript so would be going in blind. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Yeah that's what i've been doing, but i was looking for something that did it quicker. @pnuts

Comment: @pnuts yeah mate i did it that way and worked a treat, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realise the question was regarding PHP but as I suggested VBScript I thought the following might be useful if you were to opt for vbscript to format the reports. Years ago I had to format a report that would often take over an hour and as the source data changed would need to be run again - so I used vbscript and cut the time down to minutes ( the vb was far more complicated than this )

I know the formatting below looks odd, there is no block comment in vbscript so a single quote is used. Anyway, hope it may give you a starting point.

I think I would be tempted to use a `Scripting Dictionary` to maintain the count of leads for each user found. [Useful guide to scripting dictionary](http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/vbscript/13992.html)

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8



' 
Const XLS_SOURCEFILE="C:\data\spreadsheet.xls"

call processxls( 1, 2, XLS_SOURCEFILE, "Sheet1")

'
' the general idea is that you supply a column index ( iKeyCol )
' and so long as there is something in that cell for each row
' the script will run ( until it hits an empty cell )
'
' the `iKeyRow` is the row to start on - if you have column headers etc
' then after that row perhaps
'
' If you set the 3rd parameter to NULL when calling the sub you will be prompted to browse for the file to use.
'
'
'
'
Sub processxls( iKeyCol, iKeyRow, filename, sheetname )
    Dim oExcel
    Dim oXLWrkBook
    Dim oXLSheet

    Dim strFilename
    Dim r: r = iKeyRow

    '*** Get the source file ***
    strFilename=getfile( filename )


    '*** Abandon if no sourcefile ***
    If( strFilename=FALSE ) Then
        Call KillObjects()
        MsgBox "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If



    '*** Create the excel object ***
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.Visible = True
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set oXLWrkBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilename)
    Set oXLSheet = oXLWrkBook.Worksheets(sheetname)

    oXLSheet.Activate






    Do While oXLSheet.Cells( r, iKeyCol ).value <> ""
        On Error Resume Next

        '*** here is where you process your data in whatever manner you need
        data=oXLSheet.Cells( r, iKeyCol ).value



        ' increment row counter - otherwise boom!
        r=r+1
    loop



    oXLWrkBook.Save
    oExcel.Quit


    Call KillObjects()


    MsgBox "All operations completed"
End Sub






























Function getfile( explicitpath )
    if( isNull( explicitpath ) or explicitpath=false )then
        Dim oShell:Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
        If ( GetOSVersion() <= 5 ) Then
            '*** Win XP & similar ***

            Dim defaultLocalDir: defaultLocalDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Desktop"
            Set oShell = Nothing

            Set cd = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")
            cd.InitialDir = initialDir
            cd.Filter = "All Files|*.*"
            cd.FilterIndex = 1

            If cd.ShowOpen = True Then
                getfile = cd.FileName
            Else
                getfile = ""
            End If

            Set cd = Nothing    

        Else
            '*** Vista onwards ***
            Dim oExec:Set oExec = oShell.Exec( "mshta.exe ""about: <input type=file id=file><script>file.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(X.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""" )
            getfile = Replace( oExec.StdOut.ReadAll, vbCRLF, "" )
            Set oExec = Nothing
        End If
    else
        getfile=explicitpath
    end if

    Set oShell = Nothing
End Function

Function GetOSVersion()
    Dim oItem
    Dim oWMI:Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
    Dim Items:Set Items = oWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
    For Each oItem in Items
        GetOSVersion = split( oItem.Version, "." )(0)
    Next
End Function

Sub KillObjects()
    If IsObject(oExcel) Then Set oExcel=nothing
    If IsObject(oXLWrkBook) Then Set oXLWrkBook=nothing
    If IsObject(oXLSheet) Then Set oXLSheet=nothing
    If IsObject(oWMI) Then Set oWMI=nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers for the info mate, think its a little bit out of my depth though haha.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot tables is easier and more quicker